# Microsoft Graph API $filter=substringof() not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I try the API as below, but the response message is "Invalid filter clause".

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedgroups?$filter=substringof(name,'WIO')
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

The API is [OData V4](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/) compliant, which does not have substringof function ([reference](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398116)).

Also, "me/joinedGroups" is not a supported query. Please use "me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:a eq 'unified')" to find all unified groups the user is a member of. Additional filter clauses in above query is not supported at the moment.

Comment: I try `Get "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:a eq 'unified')"` But it response the groups that I am not a member of.

Comment: Can you please share value of request-id header in the response of above request along with timestamp?

Comment: The information from response headers is, `request-id: 61976c16-1bea-48d9-ad90-5cf1a94815f6
client-request-id: 61976c16-1bea-48d9-ad90-5cf1a94815f6 Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 06:53:12 GMT`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using '$search' instead if applicable:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?ConsistencyLevel=eventual&$search="givenName:Jo" OR "surname:smith"`

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$top=2&ConsistencyLevel=eventual&$search="displayName:Group Name"`